# How to increase a mic output level?

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, signal-processing, microphone, troubleshooting

I have an old lapel mic that outputs a signal that is way too small for most applications. In my attempts to learn electronics I started analyzing it and reading about the subjects. Still, I'm left with more questions than answers.

The first surprise to me was the way its circuit is built. I'm including a schematic below. It seems to be reversed in many ways: the output of signal that I've seen usually coming from between the mic and resistors is connected to the sleeve of the plug (shouldn't the sleeve be ground?) and the coupling capacitor couples the tip to ground (?).

One other problem I noticed is that the plug itself presents a high resistance between its wire connectors and tip. This only affects the tip. The resistance between the solder point and the tip is 40Ω (with the best connection to the tip I could make). I find this to be a problem but since nothing is making sense to me in this circuit I'm doubting myself in regards to whether I should replace the plug or not.

I also analyzed the output with an oscilloscope to grab some measurements (I made a connection to the wires since connecting to the plug means a much weaker signal). It works, although I'm puzzled by the negative bias. Shouldn't the mic be completely AC?

Later I plugged it into my computer audio interface. Again — it works, although it needs a lot of amplification. While doing this I noticed the interface affects the bias of the microphone.

Summing it all up (in multiple questions, which I know is not ideal):

- Is this circuit designed properly?
- Should I replace the plug? My goal is to get a stronger signal.
- Is the negative bias normal?
- Why does plugging it into the interface affects its bias?

*Note about* C1: Since it is old, I also considered the possibility of this capacitor being defective. My results after testing on the LCR meter indicate an ESR of 2.9Ω and 8.3µF, @ 1kHz as well as a phase of -81º.

[image: Circuit]
[image: Mic]

Whistling a tone:
[image: oscilloscope]

Quiet:
[image: oscilloscope]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as DC current flows the right way through the microphone, it doesn't matter which side you place the biasing resistors. The microphone drops maybe 0.5V, leaving the remaining 1V across the resistors, and that's all that matters.

Due to this being battery powered, the signal leaving this system is completely isolated and single ended. It doesn't matter which side of the signal is carried by core or sleeve, electrically there's no difference.

It *would* be an important consideration if the output were two *differential* signals, in which case those signals would be carried on cores of the cable, and the shield/sleeve would be grounded at the receiver. It would also make a big difference if this unit, and the amplifier it's connected to, shared a common ground. Then you'd be daft to use the core as ground, defeating the purpose of the cable's shield.

It is unusual to see the capacitor connected to the battery terminal, but again, in this single ended, isolated system, it is electrically no different from placing it in the path from microphone output. I suspect that the main design consideration here was ease of construction, rather than conformity with convention. It may have been easier for the person building this to connect the capacitor to the battery terminal, rather than the microphone.

Also, since the signal at the junction of R1 and microphone is fluctuating equally with respect to DC on either battery terminal, it doesn't matter which side of that DC source is considered "ground". In fact, you might even say that it's the output that is ground, DC, and that it's the battery terminals that are going up and down. The two perspectives are equivalent in this simple circuit.

The output impedance of this system is \$R_1 + R_2 = 2k\Omega\$. An additional 40Ω of cable/connector impedance is not going to make much difference to output amplitude.

If connecting a load to this output causes the biasing state of the microphone to change, that's due to DC leakage current via the capacitor. As long as the junction between R1 and the microphone stays well within the 0V to +1.5V range, its impact on output fidelity/amplitude will be insignificant. You could use a smaller ceramic capacitor if this bothers you.

If you want to get a larger signal amplitude out of this microphone, then you'll need an active pre-amplifier, low noise of course. The classic TL061 and NE5532 were often used in this role, but you can search for a more modern, better device.

Here's a really basic one, using the TL061, running off a 9V battery, and having +20dB (×10) voltage gain:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Cd8R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The microphone appears to be an electret type that requires a bias and produces a current output. The current is converted to a voltage by R1 and R2. I expect that it will need amplification.

The circuit is actually completely floating including the voltage cell. The ground symbol on the diagram is misleading. It is there to indicate the connection point for the 1.5V cell negative terminal only. It does not mean ac ground. It is not used as ac ground but as the output signal. I have removed it in my diagram because I show the cell fully wired in.

The output is coupled through the capacitor to the tip.

If plugging it in changes the dc bias voltage then either:

1. The capacitor is defective.
2. The amplifier load is supplying a current to the tip. The capacitor is electrolytic so a current would flow reverse through the capacitor. Measure the T-S voltage across the amplifier input without the microphone plugged in.
3. you are somehow misinterpreting the measurement.

The output impedance is about 2000 ohms.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZWapEm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>